# save change history using PDI

Tags: mysql, pentaho, etl

I want to have the historical value of each field associated to my fact. 
I have four fields which are `id`, `status`, `technical group` and `technicien`. the history is saved in an other table and contain `id`, `itemtype`, `date_mod`, `old_value` and `new_value`.

The result format is like:

```
'id'####'valid from'####'valid-to'####'status'####'technical group'####'technicien'
x#######date1###########date2#########X###########Y####################Z
x#######date2###########date3#########X###########Y1###################Z
x#######date3###########date4#########X###########Y1###################Z1
```

how can i do this using Pentaho Data Integration.

Thanks

Comment: Will this process run daily?

Comment: NO. for the moment i already have data in my DB. and normally i have to run the process monthly

Comment: In kettle you have an option get system info, you can use that and insert/update the data for inserting the required data.

Comment: My problem is how to manage data to have the output on the above specified format

Answer (score 1):

PDI has a step, *[Dimension lookup/update](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Dimension+Lookup-Update)*, to deal with changing dimension values. It features an automatic handle of history maintaining, provided a star structure in your data warehouse.

It works best when you adopt a dw design *[a la Kimball](http://www.kimballgroup.com/1997/08/02/a-dimensional-modeling-manifesto/)*, with each dimension (e.g. technician) having a surrogate key (an incrementing integer, for instance) used as FK in fact table.

The business key, for instance the code that identify a technician in the legacy system, will live in the dimension helping to identify all facts related to that technician, when you need to query the facts.

When something about your tech changes (for instance her address), dimension lookup step will generate a new id, a new version number and arrange the date range accordingly.

Comment: thanks for the answer but the change affect the fact table and not the value associated to dimensions. i need to merge history and data in the same table.

Comment: That sounds strange.. and would not work well with mondrian. Maybe you need to reconsider the grain of the fact

Comment: The change should NOT affect the fact table. A record on the fact table points to 1 record in the dimension. If, later, the dim record is updated, the new facts point to the updated one, the old facts point to the old record (SCD Type II). date_from, date_to and version allow you to track changes, but are not relevant for joining the dimension and the fact table. I agree with Codek here, re-evaluate your grain.